# Selenium - Wait for all elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have something like this

```
check_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_name('FILE_ID')
for box in check_boxes:
    mySelectElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(box))
    mySelectElement.click()
```

I would like to wait for every element matched by `find_elements_by_name('FILE_ID')`. There are two checkboxes.

But it throws an error:

```
find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not FirefoxWebElement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the value of **`expected_conditions`** should be a [`locator`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) instead of `WebElement`.

But you can try following code:

```
check_boxes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.NAME, 'FILE_ID')))
for box in check_boxes:
    box.click()
```